# Callback on custom function

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I have a function like this

```
function is_register(user_id){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "functions.php",
        data: {user_id: user_id, action: "is_registred"}
    }).done(function(data) {
        return data;
    });
}
```

I want to execute this function somewhere else in my code, but it doesn't work :

```
is_register(user_infos.id, function(is_registred_status){   
    console.log(is_registred_status);
}
```

As you can see, I want the "is_register" function to be completly executed before continue, so I make a callback function to log the result. Where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

Just adding a function as a parameter doesn't make it a "callback" :)
You will have to call it inside of `is_register` at the "correct" place.

Another issue is the `.done()` part in your `is_register` function. In the passed callback function you're returning the value received by the `$.ajax()` call. But this is useless as the value will not be accessible ([How to return the response of an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call))

In this case I would instead return the return value of `$.ajax()` ([jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)) and move the `.done()` part outside of the `is_register` function.

```
function is_register(user_id){
    return $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "functions.php",
        data: {user_id: user_id, action: "is_registred"}
    })
}

is_register(user_infos.id)
    .done(function(is_registred_status){   
        console.log(is_registred_status);
    };
```

Comment: hey buddy, you need to add some description along with your code, its a bad quality code. didn't expect this from someone of your reputation.

Answer (score 1):

```
function is_register(user_id , callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "functions.php",
        data: {user_id: user_id, action: "is_registred"}
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(callback)
            callback(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **jQuery.when()**, It Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

**jQuery Code:**

```
function is_register(user_id){
  return $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "functions.php",
    data: {user_id: user_id, action: "is_registred"}
  }).done(function(data) {
     return data;
  });
}

$.when(is_register(user_infos.id)).done(function(){
    console.log(is_registred_status);
});
```

*Note:If its just a single deferred object your targetting like tin this case, then you dont need to use `$.when()`, instead the `.done()/.success()` callback can be used for that purpose.*

Comment: This won't work as the return value of `is_register` is `undefined`

Comment: Ahhh, didnt notice that, now `is_register()` will return a deferred object